# How to make UISearchController inactive when switching views

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

A little background on the setting of our views:

Inside a `NavigationController`, we have a `UITabBarController` (with 3 tabs) with a `UIViewController` that has a `UISearchController`.

There is an error that if we leave the `UISearchController` active and switch to another view, when we return to the search view the entire screen is black.
However, when the `UISearchController` is not active and we switch views this does not happen.

We have tried to set the controller to not be active when segueing between views; however, when the `UISearchController` is active none of the segueing events get called (no log prints appear from `viewWillDissapear`, `viewWillAppear`, etc.)

Looking on other threads, we tried setting `self.definesPresentationContext = true`
but that does not work.

Has anyone else had this problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you add your code, I have a similar setup and I am not facing any such issues with `UISearchController`

Comment: Did you make sure that there's no custom code in `viewWillDisappear` messing with the search controller? Setting `self.definesPresentationContext = true` also didn't work for me at first because before I had been trying to remove the search controller on `viewWillDisappear`. Once I removed that code, it worked (search controller remains while switching tabs and no black screen).

Comment: Any fix for this? I've got the same issue and setting `self.definesPresentationContext = true` just hides the nav bar and my search bar

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the searchbarController active like this

```
self.resultSeachController.active = false
```

before you move on the next View

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved it as follows:

I extended `UITabBarController` and created a custom class `TabBarController`

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController  {
```

In that class I implemented its `didSelectItem` method, and in that method I called a method of the view controller that closes the search controller

```
// UITabBarDelegate
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
    let vc = viewControllers![selectedIndex] as! CommonViewController
    if vc.searchController.active {
        vc.searchBarCancelButtonClicked_NoReload()
    }
}
```

`viewControllers` is an array in `UITabBarController` that keeps all the view controllers belonging to the `UITabBarController`, and 'selectedIndex' is the index of the Tab (and the view controller) which was displayed, and thus one can get to the viewController that has the searchController active.

In my app all the view controllers are subclasses of a root class named `CommonViewController` where I put all the vars and methods that are common to all view controllers, such as all the search functionality. Therefore I simply check if the search controller is active and if it is I call a method that makes it inactive and does some other related cleanup.